# In a powershell DSC resource declaration, what syntactical element is the declaration?

Tags: powershell, dsc

I'm trying to figure out what syntactical element is in use for a Powershell DSC resource declaration.  For example:

```
    SqlServerNetwork "RDBMS"
    {
        DependsOn = @("[SqlSetup]RDBMS")
        InstanceName = "MSSQLSERVER"
        ProtocolName = "tcp"
        IsEnabled = $true
        TCPPort = 1433
        RestartService = $true 
    }
```

What exactly is the syntactical block between (and including) the two braces?  It's not a hashtable (no `@`) nor is it a scriptblock (cos that would make the properties be Powershell statements).  It feels like a parameter to the resource, so I'd like to understand the syntax.

Comment: If you add a `.GetType()` to the end of `{ }` what comes back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find any definitive reference, but I think the entire `SqlServerNetwork "RDBMS" { … }` is a Dynamic Keyword Statement, and the `{ … }` are "properties".

If you look at the source code for the PowerShell parser here:

https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/720e842c86722e9fb51e191c39bd8307d79da11a/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/parser/Parser.cs#L3579

there's this comment:

```cs
///     keyword [parameters] [name] { a=1; b=2; } # constructor with properties
```

in the xml comments for the `DynamicKeywordStatementRule` function, which matches the syntax of the DSC block.

If that's the case, the reference for `DynamicKeywordStatementAst` is here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.language.dynamickeywordstatementast?view=pscore-6.0.0

That's as far as I can get though. Hopefully someone else can give some more details.

Comment: Wow - that's a great find.  I knew DSC added new syntax elements and I guess this is it..  (Now I'll walk away slowly from this mine field!)